# Binding the displayed pattern (Path) to data model/How to make paths the same dimensions

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, viewmodel

#### Background

[Feel free to skip this]

I'm building a program that deals with horses, their owners, and the owner's racing colours (silks). This question is about a `UserControl`, called `SilksControl` that acts as a view for the `JockeySilks`.

To represent the silks I use the following class of enums:

```
public class JockeySilks
{
    public BodyPatterns BodyPattern { get; set; }
    public Colour BodyColour1 { get; set; }
    public Colour BodyColour2 { get; set; }

    public SleevePatterns SleevePattern { get; set; }
    public Colour SleeveColour1 { get; set; }
    public Colour SleeveColour2 { get; set; }

    public CapPatterns CapPattern { get; set; }
    public Colour CapColour1 { get; set; }
    public Colour CapColour2 { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, there's different patterns and colours for each element of the jockey silks. The main portion of each element is the [Item]Colour1, and the pattern is filled with [Item]Colour2.

The basic composition of the `SilksControl` is a `ViewBox` that contains a `Canvas` which in turn contains a number of `Path`s. I drew each of the patterns as `Path`s inside a child `Canvas`.

[Here's a picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpcL2.png) In this example, `CapPattern` and `BodyPattern` are set to `Plain`, and `ArmPattern` is set to `Chevrons`.

### The Problem

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set the pattern based on a WPF data binding. However, there's one issue: each pattern `Path` has different `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` values and dimensions.
By "best way" I mean something that's simple, readable and easy to implement.

#### Approaches I've thought about

1. Switching the path in code - maybe something like `pthCapPattern = CapPatterns[SilksModel.CapPattern]` where `CapPatterns` is a `Dictionary<CapPattern,Path>` or maybe accessing it from the resources

   - But not a binding, I'd have to implement some events and stuff
2. Binding the content of some control/panel to the `SilksModel.[Item]Pattern` with a converter that generates/pulls a Path from resources/dictionary

   - Which control?
   - Could have to generate entire new Path
   - Somewhat resource intensive
3. Have all the `Path`s in the XAML and change the visibility of each

   - This is just awkward and weird
4. Figure out a way to reconcile the differences in dimensions then create 1 path and bind to its `Path.Data` property (probably have some `StreamGeometry` in the resources, using a converter to go from enum to `StreamGeometry`)

   - I have no idea how to give them the same dimensions and hence `Canvas` offsets. :(

So solution 4 is my preferred solution but as I mentioned, I have no idea how I could do it, and my Googling skills can't come up with anything useful. Failing that, solution 2 would be the next best thing but I don't know of any containers that offer the same functionality as a canvas and offer binding to the children/content.

### EDIT 1:

```
<Canvas x:Name="SPatterns" Height="173" Canvas.Left="6.8" Canvas.Top="107" Width="236.6">
    <Path x:Name="Chevrons" Fill="{Binding SilksModel.BodyColour2, Converter={StaticResource DBColourToColorConverter}, ElementName=root" Height="134.125" Canvas.Left="1.087" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="21.667" Width="234.168" Data="M21.750001,94.749999 L34.000002,117.66218 30.625003,133.62501 17.000006,113.32909 0.5,126.75 3.2500048,108.125 z M212.418,93.416999 L230.918,106.79199 233.668,125.41701 217.168,111.99609 203.543,132.292 200.168,116.32917 z M32.25,48.374999 L44.250004,72.249999 40.625004,90.249999 28.000003,68.581336 7.750001,82.249999 11.665709,64.166339 z M201.918,47.041991 L222.50229,62.833335 226.418,80.916991 206.168,67.248336 193.543,88.916999 189.918,70.916991 z M41,1.8329993 L55.000002,28.166337 51.66667,45.832999 37.333336,23.499837 16.666001,37.417269 21.66571,19.418135 z M193.168,0.5 L212.50229,18.085143 217.502,36.084262 196.83467,22.166836 182.50133,44.499991 179.168,26.833333 z" />
    <!-- More SleevePatterns -->
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Hi, could we see how one of your patterns is defined (e.g. `Chevrons`)?

Comment: As I said, I just drew a Path in a Canvas - moving the geometry data around into something else is an option that I would definitely take up - nonetheless, I'll add the `Chevrons` Path into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the cleanest solution, but would something like this work for you (Obviously you'd move the geometry initialisation out of the constructor)?

You could create your suggested `Dictionary<CapPattern,Path>` object and populate it with your path information, but also apply a `Transform` to the `Geometry` to give it your desired dimensions/offset, relative to the `Canvas`.

```
public partial class Horses : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public enum CapPattern { ChevronPattern, SomeOtherPattern };
    public Dictionary<CapPattern, Geometry> Patterns { get; set; }

    private Geometry currentPath;
    public Geometry CurrentPath
    {
        get { return this.currentPath; }
        set 
        { 
            this.currentPath = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Horses()
    {
        Patterns = new Dictionary<CapPattern, Geometry>();          

        Patterns.Add(
            CapPattern.ChevronPattern,
            Geometry.Combine(
                Geometry.Parse("M21.750001,94.749999 L34.000002,117.66218 30.625003,133.62501 17.000006,113.32909 0.5,126.75 3.2500048,108.125 z M212.418,93.416999 L230.918,106.79199 233.668,125.41701 217.168,111.99609 203.543,132.292 200.168,116.32917 z M32.25,48.374999 L44.250004,72.249999 40.625004,90.249999 28.000003,68.581336 7.750001,82.249999 11.665709,64.166339 z M201.918,47.041991 L222.50229,62.833335 226.418,80.916991 206.168,67.248336 193.543,88.916999 189.918,70.916991 z M41,1.8329993 L55.000002,28.166337 51.66667,45.832999 37.333336,23.499837 16.666001,37.417269 21.66571,19.418135 z M193.168,0.5 L212.50229,18.085143 217.502,36.084262 196.83467,22.166836 182.50133,44.499991 179.168,26.833333 z"),
                Geometry.Empty, 
                GeometryCombineMode.Union, 
                new TranslateTransform(0, 0)));
        Patterns.Add(
            CapPattern.SomeOtherPattern, 
            Geometry.Combine(
                Geometry.Parse("M21.750001,94.749999 L34.000002,117.66218 30.625003,133.62501 17.000006,113.32909 0.5,126.75 3.2500048,108.125 z M212.418,93.416999 L230.918,106.79199 233.668,125.41701 217.168,111.99609 203.543,132.292 200.168,116.32917 z M32.25,48.374999 L44.250004,72.249999 40.625004,90.249999 28.000003,68.581336 7.750001,82.249999 11.665709,64.166339 z M201.918,47.041991 L222.50229,62.833335 226.418,80.916991 206.168,67.248336 193.543,88.916999 189.918,70.916991 z M41,1.8329993 L55.000002,28.166337 51.66667,45.832999 37.333336,23.499837 16.666001,37.417269 21.66571,19.418135 z M193.168,0.5 L212.50229,18.085143 217.502,36.084262 196.83467,22.166836 182.50133,44.499991 179.168,26.833333 z"), 
                Geometry.Empty, 
                GeometryCombineMode.Union, 
                new TranslateTransform(20, 30)));           

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementaton.

}
```

In my mock up, I've populated a `ComboBox` from that dictionary which sets a property `CurrentPath`, which is bound to a `Path` on the `Canvas`:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Patterns}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentPath}"
                  SelectedValuePath="Value"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Key"/>
        <Canvas>
            <Path Data="{Binding Path=CurrentPath}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

You would retain your binding for `Fill` and other properties.

Another approach could be to make a small `Class` which held your `Path` information, alongside the required `Top`, `Left`, `Transform` or any other information required to position the pattern. You could then bind a list of those objects to a `ComboBox` in a way similar to the above, and bind all the required properties on `Canvas` and `Path` to the properties of the currently selected object.

**Edit:**

You may also be able to configure your transforms in a `ResourceDictionary` along these lines:

```
<Path x:Name="Chevrons" Fill="{Binding SilksModel.BodyColour2, Converter={StaticResource DBColourToColorConverter}, ElementName=root" Data="M21.750001,94.749999 L34.000002,117.66218 30.625003,133.62501 17.000006,113.32909 0.5,126.75 3.2500048,108.125 z M212.418,93.416999 L230.918,106.79199 233.668,125.41701 217.168,111.99609 203.543,132.292 200.168,116.32917 z M32.25,48.374999 L44.250004,72.249999 40.625004,90.249999 28.000003,68.581336 7.750001,82.249999 11.665709,64.166339 z M201.918,47.041991 L222.50229,62.833335 226.418,80.916991 206.168,67.248336 193.543,88.916999 189.918,70.916991 z M41,1.8329993 L55.000002,28.166337 51.66667,45.832999 37.333336,23.499837 16.666001,37.417269 21.66571,19.418135 z M193.168,0.5 L212.50229,18.085143 217.502,36.084262 196.83467,22.166836 182.50133,44.499991 179.168,26.833333 z" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="20" Y="120"/>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

Comment: (The UserControl is called `SilksControl`)

Comment: That's pretty clever, thanks. Question: why is there a need for a Geometry.Empty?

Comment: Without it, you could refactor the patterns into XAML resource files which would make sense in terms of View-(Model|ViewModel|Controller) separation

Comment: I'm using the `Geometry.Combine` method to apply the `Transform`, but the method requires a second `Geometry` to combine (so I'm using an empty one). You could, if you didn't need the transform, just use `Geometry.Parse("Geometry Here")`.

Comment: Now that I think about it, if you're defining all your `Paths` in Xaml, you just be able to define your transforms there instead, I'll add a slight edit above.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck with your silks =D

Comment: Just noticed that you made Chevrons a Path - it should be a geometry. I'll edit

Comment: Unfortunately attempting to transform the path is ineffectual both via code and XAML. I think I'll go with option 3 and find a container. Thanks though